# Why the JSON data is not getting converted into an array in following case?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Following is my code :

```
$json_body = $application->request->getBody();
    /*echo "JSON Body : ".$json_body; 
    die;
prints following data :
JSON Body : 
{  “current_user_id”:901
   "user_id":990
}
*/

$request_data = json_decode($json_body, true); // Parse the JSON data to convert that into an assoc. array
print_r($request_data); die;//This statement prints nothing
```

I'm not getting why the array is notgetting printed after executing the statement `$request_data = json_decode($json_body, true);`

Please somebody help me.

Comment: `“` not equals `"` character. Seems not valid the json you get from `$application->request->getBody();`

Comment: do a `var_dump($json_body);` to check if the type of that variable is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string is invalid. Missing the comma and `“` not equals `"`

Valid JSON:

```
{
  "current_user_id": 901,
  "user_id": 990
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `$application->request->getBody();` method is returning an invalid JSON string

```
{  “current_user_id”:901
   "user_id":990
}
```

It's missing a comma ( , ) after the `901` value, should be something like this:

```
{
    "current_user_id":901,
    "user_id":990
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if it's related but the quotation marks used on  `“current_user_id”` might not be supported: 
`“` is diferent from `"`